# Android Junit test generator

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

Im currently working on a very large and complex application that is already mostly written and I would like to auto generate tests. Ive played with the Robotium Recorder and testdroid recorder and I was wondering if anybody had seen or heard of other similar tools. Possibly some free ones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly know about robotium which i seen at https://code.google.com/p/robotium/

beside this you can look at

https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/junit/test_case_generation

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/15625

however i never used but i heard a lot about this from my friends

**http://testdroid.com/**

Comment: You can also try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which has a recorder or generator [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) also with a new version on its way [culebratester](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/)